# AWS lambda alternative due to memory exceeded

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a program triggered by S3 put object, then create a JSON file as output on S3.

Recently, the input gets bigger so that the execution sometimes exceeds the memory (3GB) and Gets timeout (15sec).

I feel like this is the time being away from lambda but I’m not sure yet what product on AWS I should use.

Any suggestions? The event trigger (an object being put into S3) is mandatory and the program is written in Python.

Comment: An EC2 instance, perhaps?

Comment: Is the generation of JSON files a hard requirement? Might be time to rethink how you are storing data if you're generating JSON large enough to exceed 3GB of memory